# Can we detect whether a phone has a front facing motorized camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using a library that creates a device fingerprint by reading data about different sensors. When I read the camera fingerprint it pops the front camera of phone. I would like to skip this code for devices that have a motorized front camera.

Is there a simple way other than keeping a list of devices that have a motorized camera?